# Openerp Key error throwing when one2many field in one calss calling in as a related field in another

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I have another issue , please help me again. 
I have this four class named "Department, Division,Section" like bellow

Department

```
    class dept_new_registration(osv.osv):
    _name = "hr.dept.n.registration"
    _description = "depts"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Dept Name', size=128, required=True),
        'company_id': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Company Name', required=True),
        'divisions': fields.one2many('hr.division.n.registration', 'dept_id', 'Division'),
        'resres':fields.one2many('res.users','alias_id')
#   'deptdept':field.integer('For Dept Ref'),
    }

dept_new_registration()
```

Division

```
class division_new_registration(osv.osv):
    _name = "hr.division.n.registration"
    _description = "Divisions"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Division Name', size=128, ),
        'dept_id': fields.many2one('hr.dept.n.registration', 'Dept. Name', select=True, required=True),
        'sections': fields.one2many('hr.section.n.registration', 'section_id', 'Section'),
#   'dividivi':fields.integer('For Division Ref'),
    }

division_new_registration()
```

Section

```
class section_new_registration(osv.osv):
    def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
        vals = {}
        divi_id = self.pool.get('hr.division.n.registration').browse(cr,uid, values['section_id']).id
        divi_name = self.pool.get('hr.division.n.registration').browse(cr,uid, divi_id).name

        dept_id = self.pool.get('hr.division.n.registration').browse(cr,uid, values['section_id']).dept_id.id
        dept_name = self.pool.get('hr.dept.n.registration').browse(cr,uid, dept_id).name


        name = str(dept_name) + '/' +str(divi_name) + '/' + str(values['section_name'])
        values.update({'name': name})

        return super(section_new_registration, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)


    _name = "hr.section.n.registration"
    _description = "sections"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name', size=128), 
        'complete_name':fields.char('New Loacation'),       
        'section_name': fields.char('Section Name', size=128, required=True),
        'section_id': fields.many2one('hr.division.n.registration', 'Division Name', select=True, required=True),
        'test_id':fields.integer('Test'),


    }

section_new_registration()
```

I have linked all four of them successfully in **hr_department** table and that store the values for create the company structure.
in **hr_department** ,

```
_columns = {
   'name': fields.char('Segment Name', size=64, required=True, ),
   'complete_name': fields.char('Complete Name'),
    'parent_id': fields.many2one('hr.department', 'Parent Segment', select=True),
    'child_ids': fields.one2many('hr.department', 'parent_id', 'Child Departments'),
    'note': fields.text('Employment Remarks'),

    'company_id': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Company', select=True, required=False),

    'section_id':fields.many2one('hr.section.n.registration','Section'),

    'devision_id':fields.related('section_id','section_id', type="many2one", relation='hr.division.n.registration',string='Devision', store=True),
    'depart_id':fields.related('devision_id', 'dept_id',  type="many2one", relation='hr.dept.n.registration',string='Department', store=True),


}
```

What I need is , I need to call all these four columns in **hr_employee** table as it is and when I call that like bellow, it throws a keyError each and every time. please help me with this,
in **hr_employee**

```
'sec_id': fields.related('department_id', 'section_id', type="many2one", relation='hr.department',string='Section',store=True),
     'division_id':fields.related('department_id','devision_id', type="many2one", relation='hr.department', string='Division', store=True),
     'departmnt_id':fields.related('department_id', 'depart_id',  type="many2one", relation='hr.department',string='Department', store=True),
     'comp_id': fields.related('department_id', 'company_id', type="many2one", relation='hr.department',string='Company',store=True),
```

Please help me with this and thank you so much in advance

Comment: please post the trace of the exception

Comment: The last line only indicating "KeyError:" with number and that number happened to be id of the section_n'_registration class which I selected at the hr_employee    (eg:-  KeyError: 604 )